# brace initialization for specialized vector template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initialization, parameter-passing

I have this 3D vector template

```
template <class TYPE, class VEC> 
class Vec3TYPE{
public:
union{
    struct{ TYPE x,y,z; };
    struct{ TYPE a,b,c; };
    TYPE array[3];
};
inline void set( const VEC& a ){ x=a.x; z=a.y; z=a.z; };
inline void add( const VEC& a ){ x+=a.x; z+=a.y; z+=a.z; };
// + some other methods .... doesn't matter
}
```

specialized for double float and int

```
class Vec3i : public Vec3TYPE< int,    Vec3i > {  };
class Vec3f : public Vec3TYPE< float,  Vec3f > {  };
class Vec3d : public Vec3TYPE< double, Vec3d > {  };
```

I would like to do following things:

Initialize array of Vec3d by braces, like this:

```
Vec3f myVec3fs[2] = { {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f}, {3.0f,2.0f,1.0f} };
```

pass {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f} to a function as an argument of type Vec3f, like this:

```
float someFunc( const Vec3f& a );
float result = someFunc( {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f} );

Vec3d myVec3f;
myVec3f.set( {3.0f,2.0f,1.0f} );
myVec3f.add( {1.0f,2.0f,3.0f} );
```

Before i generalized my Vec3 class using templates ( i.e. when I defined Vec3d from scratch ), it was working just fine (at least with C++11 standard ).

Comment: What is the error and where do you specify the template parameters? The Compiler can't deduce them from the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that by having `Vec3X` inherit from `Vec3TYPE`, you disqualify it as an aggregate type, so you can't just use aggregate initialization like you would like to. The way to fix this is to make your types *aliases* for the corresponding `Vec3Type` instantiation:

```
//just take one template param, we can work out what the second was
template <class TYPE> 
class Vec3TYPE{
    //typedef VEC here
    using VEC = Vec3TYPE<TYPE>;
    //same as you had previously
};

//alias instead of inherit
using Vec3i = Vec3TYPE<int>;
using Vec3f = Vec3TYPE<float>;
using Vec3d = Vec3TYPE<double>;
```